# Does one light candles by the Bima when not an Avel?

Tags: minhag, chazzan-prayer-leader, chabad, lighting

When someone is a chazzan during his mourning period, [the Lubavitch custom](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/67.htm) is to light five candles.

Does a Chazzan who is not a mourner light any candles? I have seen people turn on an "electric menora" by the Bima. Is this meant to replace the candles (and one who has no menora should light candles) or is this an independent custom?

Moreover, how many candles should this "menorah" have?

Comment: The custom by whom? I don't think I've heard of this one before.

Comment: What is your source for "the custom is to light five candles"? I have seen many differing numbers in many differing Shuls.

Comment: @GershonGold http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: Closely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81833

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/howto/wizard_cdo/aid/365935/jewish/The-Amud-Lectern.htm):

> In many synagogues there is a five or seven branched candelabra (Menorah) located on or near the amud. It is illuminated with electric bulbs, and is in remembrance of the candelabra of the Temple. In some synagogues it may be displayed near the ark.
>
> Many have the custom to light two candles near the Lectern. When the leader ("Chazan") is a mourner, or leading the congregants on a Yahrtzeit, five candles are lit.

They do not bring a source.

Comment: In Sefer HaMinhagim it says, "At [each of the three daily] prayer services, five candles are lit [in front of the person observing yahrzeit who is leading the congregation]."  Foot note number 733 says" The five candles represent [the five levels of the soul, known as] nefesh, ruach, neshamah, chayah and yechidah. (From a talk of the Previous Rebbe.)"