# Candles or lights at the amud

Tags: chazzan-prayer-leader, tefillah-betzibbur

I have noticed that quite a few shuls have candles or electric lights at the amud where the chazzan davens from. These are well lit establishments and I don't the lights are there for a practical reason, especially when they use candles. It seems that this is a more chassidish minhag.

I can't think of any reason other than that it **used** to be a practical necessity, no longer is, but as we often find, people just haven't changed their practice.

Any ideas?

Comment: Closely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15584

Comment: how many and who turns them on? There is a minhag to light 5 candles by an אָבֵל when he is baal tefila

Comment: @GershonGold If it's a duplicate, it's of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51254/candles-by-the-amud?noredirect=1&lq=1 (really https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18862/what-is-the-reason-for-the-lights-lit-on-the-desk-of-the-prayer-leader). I can't VTC because neither of those have upvoted or accepted answers.